# Failed to access Mysql after trying to move `/var/lib/mysql`

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

At first, I tried to move my databases to a new directory `/media/external_drive`.

I followed some instructions on the web, like this one:

http://article.my-addr.com/?show=linux_ubuntu_change_datadir-move_mysql_database_to_other_path

After that, it seems that I can restart mysql by `sudo service mysql restart`.

However, when I tried `mysql -u root -p`, I always got the following error:

`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

Then I searched `sudo find / -name mysqld.sock`, and got no results.

I also tried to move the databases file (`mysql`) back to `/var/lib/mysql`, and undid all the things for moving the databases. Still the above error came out.

I am totally lost. Please help!

Below is the current `my.cnf`. I changed `datadir` to `/media/external_drive`, and changed back later.

```
 42 user        = mysql
 43 socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
 44 port        = 3306
 45 basedir     = /usr
 46 datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
 47 tmpdir      = /tmp
 48 skip-external-locking
```

About the permissions:

```
sudo ls -la /var/lib/mysql
total 1740832
drwx------  6 root   root         4096 2013-03-09 00:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 66 root   root         4096 2013-03-06 21:18 ..
drwx------  2 zhijia zhijia       4096 2013-03-06 16:58 AppSeq
drwx------  2 zhijia zhijia       4096 2013-03-06 17:32 AppSeq1
-rwxrwxrwx  1 zhijia zhijia          0 2013-01-24 15:47 debian-5.1.flag
-rwxrwxrwx  1 zhijia zhijia 1772093440 2013-03-06 19:43 ibdata1
-rwxrwxrwx  1 zhijia zhijia    5242880 2013-03-09 00:13 ib_logfile0
-rwxrwxrwx  1 zhijia zhijia    5242880 2013-03-06 19:35 ib_logfile1
drwx------  2 zhijia zhijia       4096 2013-01-24 15:48 mysql
-rwxrwxrwx  1 zhijia zhijia          6 2013-01-24 15:48 mysql_upgrade_info
drwx------  2 zhijia zhijia       4096 2013-01-24 15:54 phpmyadmin
```

About disk is full:

```
df
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1              9833300   7694164   1639632  83% /
none                    379568       296    379272   1% /dev
none                    383792       400    383392   1% /dev/shm
none                    383792        84    383708   1% /var/run
none                    383792         0    383792   0% /var/lock
none                    383792         0    383792   0% /lib/init/rw
none                   9833300   7694164   1639632  83% /var/lib/ureadahead/debugfs
/dev/sdb1            2930263036   1899200 2928363836   1% /media/external_drive
```

About `ps -ef | grep mysql`

```
zhijia    7329  1756  0 01:00 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

About 'sudo mysqld_safe --user=mysql`

```
130309 01:03:47 mysqld_safe Logging to syslog.
130309 01:03:47 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
130309 01:03:47 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/ubuntu.pid ended
```

About `error.log`, the following error repeats many times.

```
^G/usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13)
130309  0:00:13 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to     create it.
130309  0:00:13  InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 8.0M 
130309  0:00:13  InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool 
130309  0:00:13  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'create'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
130309  0:00:43 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
....
```

Comment: Did you edit the `my.cnf` file?

Comment: @DreamEater Yes. I changed `my.cnf` when I tried to move databases, but I changed it back after I got the error. let me show you the file content.

Comment: backup before you do something. :D

Comment: what file system does your external drive have? had a problem with NTFS / FAT once.

Comment: oh and please post the output of the mysql error log.

Comment: @steve it says `fuseblk`.

Comment: maybe try ext3 or another file system.

Answer (score 1):

This could be cause by many different reasons. Your MySQL server could not actually be running, you could be out of diskspace, it could be a permissions problem (most likely I'd think). Check out this thread for a bunch of possible fixes: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=804021.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if your `mysql` server is already running

   ```
   ps -ef | grep mysql
   ```
2. If it is, use the following command. If it isn't skip to next step.

   ```
   mysqladmin [-u ... -p...] shutdown
   ```

   where, `-u` specifies username and `-p` specifies password for the user.
3. Start mysql in safe mode with default username/root user(for mysql) to recreate/restore the `mysql.sock` file.

   ```
   mysqld_safe --user=mysql &
   ```

---

Also, provide `rwx` permissions to the user `mysql` for `/var/lib/mysql` and its chilren.

---

### EDIT

Normally, `mysql.sock` is located in `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` which it isn't. :(

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your disk is full. Try [cleaning up](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mysqld-sock-753632/#post_message_4467439), use the code below:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```